# IPython.core.error.UsageError: A return_control_callback must be supplied as a reference before a gui can be enabled

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, pycharm

I am using PyCharm Community Edition2016.2.3 on Ubuntu16.04.

I configured Show comand line afterwards.
When I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I got the ***IPython.core.error.UsageError***:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py 39312 40450 /root/PycharmProjects/mytflayer/myVQA.py
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
PyDev console: using IPython 5.1.0
Running /root/PycharmProjects/mytflayer/myVQA.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 123, in enable_gui
    return real_enable_gui(gui, app)
  File "/root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydev_ipython/inputhook.py", line 488, in enable_gui
    raise ValueError("A return_control_callback must be supplied as a reference before a gui can be enabled")
ValueError: A return_control_callback must be supplied as a reference before a gui can be enabled

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 71, in <module>
    globals = run_file(file, None, None)
  File "/root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/pydev_run_in_console.py", line 31, in run_file
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/mytflayer/myVQA.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2512, in <module>
    install_repl_displayhook()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 165, in install_repl_displayhook
    ip.enable_gui(ipython_gui_name)
  File "/root/download/pycharm-community-2016.2.3/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 125, in enable_gui
    raise UsageError("%s" % e)
IPython.core.error.UsageError: A return_control_callback must be supplied as a reference before a gui can be enabled
```

If I don't configure Show coomand line afterwards, everything works fine.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I solved my problem by install PyCharm-2016.3

Comment: If the upgrade doesn't work, try this workaround: Just uncheck the "Show command line afterwards" box in the configuration settings.
[Ref](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21330#u=1478222559100)